# Show that left multiplication by any group element is a rigid motion.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Show that left multiplication by any group element is a rigid motion. (This is needed to show that the group $F_2$ rightly covers itself two times over.)

Let $G=\langle S| R \rangle$ be a group. ($S$ is the generating set, $R$ is the relation). So we want to show that $d(g,h)=d(jg,jh)$ for any $j \in G.$ Here the distance function is defined by $d(g,h)=|g^{-1}h|$, where the length |g| is the shortest spelling of g in letters of alphabet S. Hence,

$d(jg,jh)=|(jg)^{-1}jh|=$

How should I proceed?

Comment: Can you simplify the group expression $(jg)^{-1} jh$?

Comment: @LeeMosher, is it $|()^{−1}ℎ|=|g^{-1}j^{-1}jh| = |g^{-1}h|=d(g,h)?$ I thought we need $G$ to be abelian to interchange $j$ and $g$...

Comment: The abelian hypothesis means $ab=ba$. But you don't that to deduce that $(jg)^{-1} = g^{-1} j^{-1}$, you can deduce that just by simplifying the expression $(g^{-1} j^{-1})(jg)$ using the associative law and inverse law.